# How to download a video from Google Slides

Tags: google-slides

How can you download a video that has been embedded in a Google Slides presentation?

Background: When exporting to PowerPoint videos are not exported. That's why I want to do that manually.

**EDIT**: The video is not on YouTube, but is stored on Google Drive. I don't know the filename, so finding it in Google Drive is not an option.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured it out. It's a bit of a hack, but it works:

1. Right click the video and click `Copy debug info`.
2. Paste the info into an editor or text box of your liking and find the docid: `"docid": "1akRcmXOz_wy_...qD8LooCdx-CLEV"`
3. Go to your browser and enter `https://drive.google.com/file/d/` followed by the `docid` into the addressbar. (e.g., navigate to `https://drive.google.com/file/d/1akRcmXOz_wy_...qD8LooCdx-CLEV`)
4. The video will open and you can use the download button in the top right.